# ES6 modules imported more than once?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I am struggeling to understand how exactly browsers are handling ES6 modules. I thought, that modules will only be executed the first time they are imported([modules: javascript.info][1].

Let's say i have following project structure:

```
js
  admin.js
  customers.js
  index.js 
customers.html 
index.html
```

Both `index.js` and `customers.js` import the same module `admin.js`. When i import `index.js` in `index.html` the name of `admin` is changed from "John" to "Pete" and logged as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Modules</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav><a href="customers.html">Customers</a></nav>
    <h1>Homepage</h1>
    <script type="module" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In customers.html i expected the admin's name to be "Pete" as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Customers</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav><a href="index.html">Home</a></nav>
    <h1>Customers</h1>
    <script type="module" src="js/customers.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But instead of "Pete", "John" is logged again.

Modules i used:

```
// admin.js

export let admin = {
  name: "John",
};

//index.js

import { admin } from "./admin.js";
admin.name = "Pete";

console.log(admin.name); // Pete


// customers.js

import { admin } from "./admin.js";

console.log(admin.name); // Pete
```

[1]: https://javascript.info/modules-intro#a-module-code-is-evaluated-only-the-first-time-when-imported)

Comment: *"will only be executed the first time they are imported"* on the same page (load). If you go to a new page or refresh the current page, all JavaScript is executed all over again. That has always been the case.

Comment: ok, unlike in node.js it is not possible to share a module between other modules?

Comment: No, it's possible. But opening a new page or reloading the page is like quitting the node application and restarting it (or starting a separate node process). Every page (load) is a separate environment. If you were to run `node index.js` and then `node customers.js` you would see the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Felix said above, each page render/rerender would then reload all assets. This is the difference between a Single Page Application and a Multi Page Application. You're working with an MPA, so you would need some form of data persistence between pages, such as databasing the data server side and requesting it on each page load, or placing the necessary persisted data in something like `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` for access between pages.